# How to write sqlite script that returns all rows with matching column name and any row with matching parentID?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I would like to write a sqlite script returns all rows with matching column name and any "child row"

For example:

Table ABC:

| Date | Time | Location | Who | UniqueID | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/0001 | 11pm | Room1 | Chris | 1 | '' |
| 01/01/0001 | 11pm | Room2 | David | 2 | 1 |
| 01/01/0001 | 11pm | Room2 | John | 3 | 1 |
| 01/01/0001 | 11pm | Room3 | Emily | 4 | '' |

If I do `Select * from ABC WHERE WHO is "Chris"` it will return:

| Date | Time | Location | Who | UniqueID | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/0001 | 11pm | Room1 | Chris | 1 | '' |

Instead I would like it to return the following:

| Date | Time | Location | Who | UniqueID | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/0001 | 11pm | Room1 | Chris | 1 | '' |
| 01/01/0001 | 11pm | Room2 | David | 2 | 1 |
| 01/01/0001 | 11pm | Room2 | John | 3 | 1 |

Explaination: David and John have ParentID that is equal to the selected row(s).

Comment: How many levels deep can parent child relationships be?  Are there only ever a max of depth 2, or could there be, for example, grandchildren as well?

Comment: Just 2, parent and child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you only expect two levels here in the hierarchy, you can use a simple query here:

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC
WHERE
    Who = 'Chris' OR
    ParentID = (SELECT UniqueID FROM ABC WHERE Who = 'Chris')
ORDER BY
    UniqueID;
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove any possible duplicate row in addition to the query you wrote?

Comment: It depends on what your definition of "duplicate" row is.  If you mean all six columns having the same value, then just changing to `SELECT DISTINCT *` would be sufficient.  If you mean less columns, then we can use `ROW_NUMBER`.